# Save r dataframe to google sheets

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have performed some calculations and created some data in r, it is saved to csv, but now I want to save the same dataframes (mydata) to Google Sheets.

ver. 1 : I would like to save them in google sheets format to the folder on a desctop. Is this possible?

ver2. Save directly to the Google drive. How I can here point the folder where to save the files?

I have uploaded:
library(googlesheets4)
library(googledrive)
Created the connection to drive
gs4_auth()

and then I was trying to use
a)
Sheet1 <- sheet_write(mydata)  # # this gave me a strange blank google sheet with strange name on google drive

b) I have thried to use
drive_mv("Sheet1", path = "/Users/user/Desktop/Data")
and also it returned me mistake.

Now I am totally lost, and wonder what should i do to save existing dataframe to Google Sheet? How I can indicate location where to save?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to upload a dataframe into google sheets, first you need to create the spreadsheets in google drive. Then, you need to copy the link of that sheet into the function `gs4_get`. Maybe is not the best approach, but for me works.

```
library(googlesheets4)

mydata %>%
  write_sheet(
    ss = gs4_get(
      "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/...." # Replace the access link to the spreadsheets
    ),
    sheet = "Name_your_sheet"
  )
```